# Compiler errors with Reachability classes in Xcode 3.2.6 and iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, networking, reachability

I receive several errors when I have added the Reachability class (.h/.m) from Apple themselves to an app project I am developing in Xcode 3.2.6. I want to check the internet connectivity in the app before it is going to perform an action that requires the internet connection. But as soon as I add the .h and .m files I get several errors where it mainly complains about undeclared variables and 'Expected ) before instanceType'. See the image of the following link:

http://www.johntolunay.com/reach/reachability_error.png

And yes I have added the SystemConfiguration Framework to the project and the funny thing is that I have done another app project that uses the Reachability classes and that ACTUALLY works! But why I get these errors in this app project is beyond my comprehension.

Same thing with the Tony Million version of the Reachability class, it generates several types of errors.

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: You're using an antiquated version of Xcode. You need to update.

Comment: The Reachability class that is on the developers site of Apple now is for ARC. You will need at least Xcode 4 with the iOS 5 SDK, but I would suggest you switch to Xcode 5 with the iOS 7 SDK. You will need Xcode 5 with the iOS 7 SDK if you submit your app to the AppStore